# Reusing the same process for shell commands execution in Android. What is wrong?

Tags: android, shell, process, dataoutputstream

My app uses a process in separate thread to run some commands and get the input from them:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
```

The app sends commands to the process like this:

```
public void setCommands(String[] commands)
{
    try{
        for(String command : commands){
         out.writeBytes(command + "\n");
        }
        out.writeBytes("exit\n"); //if I comment this line the commands get lost
        out.flush();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The thread then reads the input from process with BufferedReaders and sends it to the main thread and it works fine for the first time. The problem is that I want to reuse the same process with multiple calls to `setCommands()`, but after the first call the OutputStream of the process gets closed with `out.writeBytes("exit\n");` statement. If I comment this line it seems like the `out.flush()` starts to have no effect. Could somebody please explain to me why is this happening and how can this be done right?